# How to use tabsetPanel in R while using shinymaterial?

Tags: r, shiny, tabs

I am using shinymaterial and would like to develop tabsetPanels. I prefer them to material_tabs and material_tabs_content because of the insertTab function. However, when I use the tabsetPanel, they are stacked:

[image: stacked tabs]

I believe the shinymaterial packed overrides the tabsetPanel. How can I have it working properly?

ui:

```r
ui <- material_page(
    title = "Prototype",
    primary_theme_color = "#073857", 
    secondary_theme_color = "#0CA789",
    material_row(
      material_column(width = 3,
                      tags$style(HTML(".radio-inline {margin-right: 
                                      42px;}")),
                      material_card(
                        title = "Select Visualization",
                        radioButtons(
                          "table_type",
                          label = NULL,
                          choices = c("Source Data" = "t1", 
                           "Aggregated Data" = "t2", 
                           "Aggregated + Raw Data" = "t3", 
                           "Pie Chart" = "c1", "Histogram" = "c2", 
                           "Scatter plot" = "c3"),
                          width = "100%"
                        )
                      )
      ),
      material_column(width = 9,
                      material_column(width = 9,
                             tabsetPanel(id="tabs",
                             tabPanel(title="Current", 
                              material_card(title = "Visualization", 
                                        uiOutput("vis_current"))),
                                      )
                      ),
                      material_column(width = 3,
                                      material_button(
                                        input_id="new_tab",
                                        label="+"
                                      )
                      )
      )
    )
)
```

server:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- reactive({
    dataSet <- data.frame(read_excel("dataset.xlsx"))
    dataSet <- data.frame(dataSet[rowSums(is.na(dataSet)) != ncol(dataSet), 
         colSums(is.na(dataSet)) != nrow(dataSet)])

    dataSet
  })

  observeEvent(input$new_tab, {
    if(input$new_tab > 0){
      tab_name <- paste0("Tab ", input$new_tab)
      vis_name <- paste0("vis_", input$new_tab)
      output[[vis_name]] <- renderUI({
        renderText(tab_name)
      })
      insertTab(inputId = "tabs", tabPanel(title=tab_name, 
          material_card(title = tab_name, uiOutput(vis_name))))
    }
  })
 
  output$vis_current <- renderUI({
    renderText("current")
  })

}
```

As you can see, the new tabs are created on button click. Add tabs work, but they are stacked and it looks bad. Any ideas on how I can solve that? Maybe by adding some JS or css code?